# How to identify Leaflet's Marker during a `popupopen` event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, gis, openstreetmap, leaflet

when a marker is clicked, I need to execute some code that finds the `id` corresponding to the marker being clicked , retrieves data from backend API, then adds the newly retrieved data to the `content` of the popup that will open.

The only way that is able to listen to a click event on the marker is

```
map.on('popupopen', function(e){
    // How to retrieve marker?
    // eg: Assign an id on creation, retrieve it now during popupopen
};)
```

How can I find out which marker this is? Is it possible to add an `id` attribute to each marker, then retrieve this `id` during the `popupopen` event?

Comment: http://leaflet.cloudmade.com/reference.html#marker A `L.Marker` is placed on the map: `marker.addTo(map)`. I am able to pass an `id` value to each individual `marker` object. How should this be done, and how can I retrieve this `id` later during a `popupopen` event?

Comment: When creating markers, I do something like `var marker = new L.marker(
   new L.LatLng( lat, lng ));` Then `marker.setContent(content).addTo(map)`.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The event object contains a "popup" attribute that has a private attribute called "_source" which is the object that the popup is bound to (i.e. the marker).  Since _source is supposed to be private this doesn't seem like the right way but I'm not sure how else to do it.

```
map.on('popupopen', function(e) {
  var marker = e.popup._source;
});
```

Comment: I'm getting `undefined` on `e.popup._source` when opening a popup that was generated by a `L.geoJson()` call. Any clues?

Comment: My **dirty** solution on the moment was to include a `<div>` inside the popup content on `onEachFeature` and then looking it up on... `e.target._popup._contentNode.childNodes[0].attributes[0]`. Yeah, dirty, but it works. *phew*

Answer (score 18):

Javascript objects can have any properties defined on them. Set popup.marker to the referenced marker when you create the popup. Then you can access it later in the event handler.

Comment: Excellent Idea, because in my case `e.popup._source` was `null`

Comment: This answer is arguable better than the accepted one, since the `e.popup._source` can indeed be missing, for instance if the popup was opened/closed programmatically (instead of clicking).

Answer (score 3):

Other answers didn't work, but this does:

```
map.on('popupopen', function(e) { alert(e.popup._source._popup._content); });
```

Guess this library is pretty volatile ...and I'm not sure why it's this complicated to transmit such information in the first place. <shrug>

Answer (score 2):

To get the marker id, you can use this code:

```
map.on('popupopen', function(e) {
  var marker = e.popup._source.feature.properties.markerid;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to find an option which didn't use private stuff - this method sets properties on the popup which can be accessed through `popupopen` and `popupclose` events:

```js
const map = L.map('map').setView( [ 53.749943495499345, -2.058831736626878 ], 19 );
L.tileLayer( 'https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        maxZoom: 19,
        attribution: '© <a target="attribution" href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
}).addTo( map );
/* create marker */
const marker = L.marker( [ 53.749943495499345, -2.058831736626878 ] ).addTo( map );
/* set property on marker */
marker.markerid = 'delightful';
/* create popup */
const popup = L.popup().setContent('The New Delight');
/* set properties on popup */
popup.marker = marker;
popup.markerid = marker.markerid;
/* bind popup to marker */
marker.bindPopup(popup);
/* access markerid when popup opens */
map.on( 'popupopen', e => {
    console.log( e.popup.markerid );
});
/* access marker when popup closes */
map.on( 'popupclose', e => {
    console.log( e.popup.marker.markerid );
    e.popup.marker.setOpacity(0.2);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create a different listener for each popup you create :

```
yourMarker1.bindPopup(popupContent1).on("popupopen", function(event){
    //this will be fired only for this specific popup of marker1 .
});

yourMarker2.bindPopup(popupContent2).on("popupopen", function(event){
    //this will be fired only for this specific popup of marker2.
});
```