# Get multiple Markers in Leaflet

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet, markers

I'm looking for add draggable markers on a map, giving them names and then getting all markers back with names and coordinates.  I´m not able to put the name somewehere or if i put a name inside it gave it to all

```
markers.$("#addmarker").click(function () {

    var geojsonFeature = {

        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "name": "",
            "typ": "nur",
            "reichweite": ""
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [map.getCenter().lat, map.getCenter().lng]
        }
    }

    var marker;

    var geojsonlayer = L.geoJson(geojsonFeature, {

        pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng){



            marker = L.marker(map.getCenter(), {

                draggable: true,

            }).bindPopup("<div id='titel'>Unbenannter Marker</div><input type='button' value='Marker löschen' class='marker-delete-button'/><br><p>Name:<input type'text' id='setname'/><button class='trigger'>Say hi</button>");

            marker.on("popupopen", onPopupOpen);

            return marker;
        }

   layergroup.addLayer(geojsonlayer);
   layergroup.addTo(map);
   ;
});

// Function to handle delete as well as other events on marker popup open
function onPopupOpen() {

    var tempMarker = this;


    $(".marker-delete-button:visible").click(function () {
        map.removeLayer(tempMarker);

    });

function getAllMarkers() {
    var allMarkersObjArray = [];//new Array();
    var allMarkersGeoJsonArray = [];//new Array();

    $.each(map._layers, function (ml) {
        //console.log(map._layers)
        if (map._layers[ml].feature && map._layers[ml].feature.properties.typ == "nur") {

            allMarkersObjArray.push(this)
            allMarkersGeoJsonArray.push(JSON.stringify(this.toGeoJSON()))
        }
    })

    console.log(allMarkersObjArray);
    alert("Anzahl Markers : " + allMarkersGeoJsonArray.length + "\n\n" + allMarkersGeoJsonArray + "\n\n");
}
```

Maybe someone has a more simple idea.
Greets!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to access all markers created by clicking on your `#addmarker` button / link, they would simply be accessible directly in your `layergroup` variable (skipping the GeoJSON layer group that holds each of them). So if the latter contains no extra layer, your `allMarkersObjArray` should have the same content as [`layergroup.getLayers()`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#layergroup-getlayers) (but not necessarily in the same order).

A difference appears when deleting a marker: because you remove it only from map, but not from `layergroup`, the latter would keep it in memory. Simply remove it from `layergroup` (instead of from the map) should resolve this discrepancy.

As for modifying the name of your marker (in `marker.feature.properties.name`), you would simply need a way to access the marker from within your popup input. See [leafletjs how to get a handle to the active pop/marker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34504816/leafletjs-how-to-get-a-handle-to-the-active-pop-marker/34505877#34505877).

You could also assume that there is only 1 opened popup at a time (normal Leaflet configuration), and keep a reference to the "active" marker in your `onPopupOpen` function.

```js
var layergroup = L.layerGroup().addTo(map);
var activeMarker;

$("#addmarker").click(function() {

  var mapCenter = map.getCenter();

  var geojsonFeature = {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "name": "",
      "typ": "nur",
      "reichweite": ""
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [mapCenter.lat, mapCenter.lng]
    }
  };

  var geojsonlayer = L.geoJson(geojsonFeature, {

    pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
      var marker = L.marker(map.getCenter(), {
        draggable: true,
      }).bindPopup("<div id='titel'>Unbenannter Marker</div><input type='button' value='Marker löschen' class='marker-delete-button'/><br><p>Name:<input type='text' id='setname'/><button class='trigger'>Say hi</button>");

      marker.on("popupopen", onPopupOpen);

      return marker;
    }
  });

  layergroup.addLayer(geojsonlayer.getLayers()[0]); // use the only marker instead of the GeoJSON layer.

});

// Function to handle delete as well as other events on marker popup open
function onPopupOpen() {

  activeMarker = this;

  $(".marker-delete-button:visible").click(function() {
    layergroup.removeLayer(activeMarker); // Remove from layergroup instead of from map. It will be removed from map automatically.
    activeMarker = null;
  });

  $("#setname").val(activeMarker.feature.properties.name).change(modifyName);
  // val will update the displayed name in the input. May need some sanitization.
  // change will add a listener callback to update the name in memory on user input.
}

function modifyName(event) {
  var newName = event.currentTarget.value;

  activeMarker.feature.properties.name = newName;
}

function getAllMarkers() {

  var allMarkersObjArray = layergroup.getLayers();
  var allMarkersGeoJsonArray = [];

  layergroup.eachLayer(function(layer) {
    allMarkersGeoJsonArray.push(JSON.stringify(layer.toGeoJSON()));
    // You could also have used layergroup.toGeoJSON(), but it would have given a FeatureCollection, whereas here you get an array of Feature's.
  });

  console.log(allMarkersObjArray);
  alert("Anzahl Markers : " + allMarkersGeoJsonArray.length + "\n\n" + allMarkersGeoJsonArray + "\n\n");
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ve2huzxw/106/

In the case you share, there would be no need to create `geojsonFeature` just to create the marker, but you may have chosen this for other reason outside the scope of this question.

In normal Leaflet configuration, there is no more than 1 popup open at a time, so the `id='titel'` (typo?) and `id='setname'` appear only once at a time, but you should avoid taking the risk of having several elements with the same ID. If for any reason they appear simultaneously on the page, you will get unexpected results when trying to select one.

Note: there is a typo in your popup content HTML: `<input type'text' id='setname'/>` should be `<input type='text' id='setname'/>`.

Comment: perfect answer. thank you! i solved it in the meantime with the geojson creation after adding all markers and iterate over the objects in a layergroup like you said. But anyway is your soloution hellping me in other facts. Thank you!!!